# robots.txt exclude urls which contain specific part

Tags: robots.txt

I have urls like this:

- www.wunderwedding.com/weddingvenues/share-weddingvenue/175/beachclub-all-good
- www.wunderwedding.com/weddingvenues/share-weddingvenue/2567/castle-rock

Since these urls no longer exist, I want to disallow googlebot via robots.txt to access urls that contain '/share-weddingvenue/'

Will this work to achieve that?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: */share-weddingvenue/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, probably it won't work. [Here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) you'll find a good overview on what you can do in a `robots.txt`:

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines.

If the content is gone, you should better make sure to return a [Status 410](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since only few regular expressions are allowed here, the code would be:

```
Disallow: weddingvenues/share-weddingvenue/
```

More on this topic can be found here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449